# Programmatically add KeyBindings Commands

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

How should I go about adding `KeyBinding` commands programmatically based on a string? In my xaml code I have properties like the following one.

```
<KeyBinding Key="Q" Command="{Binding AcceptAndNextCommand}" />
```

This works fine but I would like to be able to add this kind of key bindings dynamically and so I want to be able to add them programmatically. I have created a project settings file where each of my `KeyBindings` is a separate row. This row possesses over a dictionary value where I have saved each keyboard key as a dictionary key and each command as a dictionary value; e.g.: `{"Key":"Q", "Value":"AcceptAndNextCommand"}`. A `String` to `KeyBinding` Key conversion works fine but I'm not sure how to add a Command to the KeyBinding based on a `String`. All the command strings in the dictionary value look like this "AcceptAndNextCommand". I was hoping that I could make this work with a `CommandConverter cv` as in my example below but that does not seem to work.

```
private void KeyboardShortcuts()
    {
        foreach (SettingsProperty property in Properties.KeyboardBindings.Default.Properties)
        {
            var propertyValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(
                Properties.KeyboardBindings.Default[property.Name].ToString());

            var keyBinding = new KeyBinding()
            {
                Key = (Key)new KeyConverter().ConvertFromString(propertyValue["Key"])
            };

            CommandConverter cv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(ICommand)) as CommandConverter;
            keyBinding.Command = (ICommand)cv?.ConvertFromString(propertyValue["Command"]);
        }
    }
```

I based my implementation on the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41998724/3658288) but it did not explain the addition of commands very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `BindingOperations.SetBinding` method to programmatically create a binding:

```
KeyBinding kb = new KeyBinding();
BindingOperations.SetBinding(kb, KeyBinding.CommandProperty, new Binding("AcceptAndNextCommand"));
...
InputBindings.Add(kb);
```

The path of a binding is just a `string`.

Comment: This does not set a keybinding in the view does it? I just ran it and it did not throw any errors but also nothing at all happened.

Comment: In the view? It sets the command of the KeyBinding that you pass to the SetBinding method...Of course you need to add the KeyBinding that you are creating programmatically to the view somehow. Or where else do you plan to use the KeyBinding?

Comment: That is what I meant with my comment. How do I add it then to the view in which the keybinding should be used?

Comment: It's in the code behind a UserControl used as the main View.

Comment: You say in your question that "In my xaml code I have properties like the following one...". Do these work? *Where* do you define them?

Comment: Yes, they work but now I'm trying to do exactly the same as in the xaml file but in its code behind. The xaml properties are define in `<UserControl.InputBindings>`. I'm not exactly sure what you mean with `where`.

Comment: Just add the KeyBinding that you create programmatically to the InputBindings collection then: this.InputBindings.Add(kb);

Comment: Then you are obviously doing something wrong. Try to hardcode the string values. And please provide a full repo of your issue if you want anyone to be able to help you any further.

Comment: If I try to print the command in the keybinding I get a null reference. This could be the reason.

Comment: The BindingOperations seem to be doing nothing on the KeyBinding.

Comment: Do you have a DataContext with an AcceptAndNextCommand property?

Comment: Yes, I do have AcceptAndNextCommand in my DataContext but does that matter for BindingOperations? I'm checking if everything gets set by just simply debugging and the only value that does not get set is the `Command` of my `keyBinding` variable.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. The binding should work. I've verified that this works. Of course you will have to wait to check the property until the binding has been resolved though.

Comment: I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong but what do you exactly mean with that I have to wait?

Comment: Again, please provide a repo of your issue if you still cannot get this to work: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve