# How to bind delete to action in Caliburn.Micro WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I'm currently trying to bind the "delete" key to an `Action` when deleting a datagrid row.

Setting a `KeyBinding` doesn't seem to work:

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Delete"
                cal:Message.Attach="[Key Delete] = [Action DeletePartNumberRow()]"/>
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

Setting it to the `DataGrid`, doesn't work either:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="PartNumbers"
          CanUserAddRows="True"
          CanUserDeleteRows="True"
          cal:Message.Attach="[Gesture Delete] = [Action DeletePartNumberRow()]">
...
</DataGrid>
```

I was wondering if there is another way of accomplishing this, or if I'm attempting this the wrong way?

Ultimately I would like to be able to create custom key bindings in the application. Is there another way that I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by deriving from System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerBase  :

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <common:InputBindingTrigger>
        <common:InputBindingTrigger.InputBinding>
            <KeyBinding Key="Delete"/>
        </common:InputBindingTrigger.InputBinding>
        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="DoTheMagic"/>
    </common:InputBindingTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

you have lot of samples on net, for example [HERE](http://www.felicepollano.com/2011/05/02/InputBindingKeyBindingWithCaliburnMicro.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that did work. Any idea how to setup global custom keyboard shortcuts that can be edited/changed?

Comment: what do you mean how to setup?  it doesnt exist a global  way to do this if its the question...each key to each action...(sorry for my poor english)

Comment: maybe by looking at Converter...but never test it in this case...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016457/dynamically-add-keybindings-in-wpf  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625859/can-i-create-a-keybinding-for-a-sequence-of-keys-in-wpf

Comment: thanks again. I think that will lead me in the right direction.